# Diamagnetic Materials and their relation with temperature

Tags: homework-and-exercises, magnetic-moment

What happens when a diamagnetic material is intensively cooled, considering the fact that Curies law doesn't hold good for diamagnetic materials ? What will be the effect on its magnetization ?